# Invalid Entity or Super Base class

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have used Symfony 2 and I have successfully configured **FOSUserBundle**.

My application works fine on windows machine in both **Production** and **Development** mode

But when I deployed it on Linux machine it works fine in Development mode but it gives a blank page in Production mode. When I check the error log file it has following error:

```
request.CRITICAL: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: Class \Entity\User is not a  
valid entity or mapped super class. (uncaught exception)

request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception 
(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: Class \Entity\User is not a valid entity or 
mapped super class.) [] []
```

Have a look into my User Entity class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration",     "Profile"})
     * @Assert\MinLength(limit="3", message="The name is too short.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\MaxLength(limit="255", message="The name is too long.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", length="255", nullable=true)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please select your Date Of Birth.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     */
    protected $dob;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please select your Date Of Birth.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     */
    protected $gender;

    /**
     * Override $email so that we can apply custom validation.
     * 
     * @Assert\Email(groups={"AppRegistration"})
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var string $firstName
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */

    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string $lastName
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $lastName;

/**
     * @var datetime $createdAt
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255", nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $facebookID;


    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255", nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $twitterID;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255", nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $twitter_username;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length="255", nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $image_path;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(name="home_town",type="string", length="255", nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $homeTown;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(name="location",type="string", length="255", nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $location;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(name="interest",type="string", length="255", nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $interest;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(name="friend",type="string", length="255", nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $friend;

/**
     * @var smallint $age
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="age", type="smallint", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $age;

    /**
     * @var string $country
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @ORM\Column(name="country_id", type="string", length=25, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $countryId;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProfileViewer", mappedBy="viewer")
     */
    protected $viewers;

    ..................
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the Entity named `User` to any other name, for example `Users`.

Because User is a reserved keyword in database. Change this and build the schema again. May be this is the mistake?